# Default Schema Problems on server

Tags: sql-server, schema, authentication

When i connect to SSMS on my server through remote desktop and query my database using:

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[database_principals] WHERE [principal_id] = USER_ID()
```

I am getting the correct results (my name is DOMAIN\Glen and the type is WINDOWS_USER)

However when i connect to SSMS as a Administrator (right clicking and selecting run as administrator) i get the following results (name is dbo and type is SQL_USER)

This is a problem for me as in the users section under DOMAIN\Glen i have the default schema set. So when i run as administrator it is not picking up the correct tables.

Plus i am a little confused on why i am connecting as a SQL_USER when my authentication is set to Windows Authentication only.

The main reason i am trying to solve this is because when i run SSMS from my local machine it is connnecting in the same way as if i run as an administrator on the server and therefore i am unable to access my tables within the defined schema. I can not add this onto my procedures as they are all hard coded and there are over 1000.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I connect with a SQL Login to my instance and run your query, it shows me as WINDOWS_USER...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say it, but best practice is to always qualify object names with the schema anyway.

This is mandatory for things like schemabound views.

Why is it best practice? See [this by Tibor Karaszi](http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/owner-schema-qualifying-object-names/) or [this by Midnight DBA](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/12/tip-schema-qualify-objects-in-sps/) or just trust me or the [MS SQL Server Best Practice Analyzer](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/tools/archive/2008/01/24/sql-server-2005-schema-integration-changes-and-use-of-best-practices-use-of-schema-qualified-tables-views.aspx)

After comment...

Have you considered [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) to make OtherSchema.mycode point to [DOMAIN\Glen].MyCode?

```
CREATE SYNONYM OtherSchema.mycode FOR [DOMAIN\Glen].MyCode
```

Comment: I get that it is best practice but unfortunatly i did not write the views or stored procedures. There must be a way around this?

Comment: @GlenRobson: added a workaround...

Comment: Im sorry but that makes no sense to me

Comment: @GlenRobson: a synonym is an alias for an object, as per my link. So your SQL_USER schema will resolve to your [DOMAIN\Glen] schema. Otherwise, fix the code

Comment: The only schemas i have in my database are my schema (GLENSSCH) and dbo. And it would take months to change every single procedure, function and view within my database. That would not be possible.

Comment: So use synonyms to mask it. NoteI use schemas but I don't use default scheme for a user: can you simply set the default schema for everyone?

Comment: I already have set the default schema for every user, but what im saying is if i remotly access the server from my machine i am connecting with the same username both on the server and on my local machine but i am getting different results on each machine?